# Two contradictory requirements (Android source project vs sensor.h)

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am working on sensors and I just read the Android documentation [here](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/composite_sensors.html) and on sensor API file ([sensor.h](https://source.android.com/devices/reference/sensors_8h_source.html))
I found some differences between the documents and even some contradictions.

For example (Step counter sensor):
In the web site Google writes:

> " reset to zero only on a **system** reboot."

But in the API file (sensor.h) they write:

> "reset to zero only on a **system / android** reboot"

Which one is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct here system is referring to system which running on android